# How to fix git prompting for "vcs@missouri.edu's password" when trying to set up new repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to create a git repository (on gitlab) from an existing directory on a university private gitlab. I can follow all the steps until pushing, when it prompts for "vcs@missouri.edu's password"

Putting in my own username's password doesn't work. I have made sure that user.name and user.email are set to my own in git config. Is there some sort of global password for the repository, or do I need to set a config somewhere to ask for my own?

$ git push -u origin master 
git@vcs.missouri.edu's password:

Comment: `git config` has some setting you need to adjust.

Comment: If your remote is set up to use SSH instead of HTTP(S), then the server needs to know about your public key.  See [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh), though the steps may be slightly different to add the key to a private server.